# Sacar el promedio de numeros contenidos en un arreglo bidimensional

Tags: c#, array

Necesito sumar números dentro del arreglo pero por renglones, y de esas 3 sumas sacar el promedio. Y por ultimo mostrar el alumno con mayor promedio. Se me hace difícil apenas soy principiante :(
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
            int sumaCal = 0;
            double prom;
            string[] alumnos = {"Pepe","Mary","Chuy"};
            int[,] cal = new int [3,4];
            cal[0,0] = 6;cal[0,1] = 7;cal[0,2] = 8;cal[0,3] = 9;
            cal[1,0] = 6;cal[1,1] = 9;cal[1,2] = 7;cal[1,3] = 9;
            cal[2,0] = 8;cal[2,1] = 9;cal[2,2] = 7;cal[2,3] = 6;

            for (i = 0; i < cal.Length; i++){
                for (j = 0; j < alumnos.Length; j++){
                    sumaCal = cal[3,4];
                    prom = sumaCal/4;
                    Console.WriteLine("La calificacion de {0} es: 2", alumnos[i], cal);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías hacerme saber si la respuesta te sirvio

Answer (score 0):

```
double sumaNotas = 0;
double promedioNotas = 0;  
double auxNotas = 0;
int indiceAlumno = 0;

for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
{
   for(int j = 0; j <= 2; j++)
   {
      sumaNotas += cal[i, j];
   }

   if(sumaNotas > auxNotas)
   {
      auxNotas = sumaNotas;
      promedioNotas = sumaNotas / 4;
      indiceAlumno = i;
   }
}

Console.WriteLine("El alumno con promedio más alto es {0} y su promedio es {1}, alumnos[indiceAlumno], promedioNotas);
```

Se recorre la matriz con dos **ciclos for** y se calcula la suma para cada fila, esta suma se guarda en la **variable sumaNotas**, después se compara esta **variable sumaNotas** con la **variable auxNota**, de ser mayor **sumaNotas** pues, se le da a **auxNota** el valor actual de **sumaNotas**, se calcula el promedio y se guarda el **índice i** en la **variable índiceAlumno**, de esta forma se va obteniendo el alumno de mayor promedio, **índiceAlumno** guardará el alumno que hasta el momento va teniendo mayor promedio, por último se imprime el resultado.