# Métodos en Java

Tags: java, matrices

Alguien me podría orientar, es mi primer semestre y me dejaron esta tarea
tengo que hacer un método para sumar la primer fila de una matriz de 3*3, otro método para la segunda, etc. Pero no sé como hacerlo en un solo método, fuera del método main
El problema es que se hacer la suma pero todo junto en el método main, el código para la suma de la primer fila es:

```
for(int i=0;i<1;i++)
        {
            sumaf=0;
            for (int j=0;j<n3;j++)
            {
                sumaf +=matriz[i][j];
            }
            System.out.println("La suma de la fila "+i+" es: "+sumaf);
        }
```

Comment: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414150/sacar-el-promedio-de-numeros-contenidos-en-un-arreglo-bidimensional/414156#414156, te puede servir

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Ya diste el primer paso.. si sabes sumar todo.. entonces sabes sumar cada pedazo por separado.. porque es lo que hace tu codigo no? si agregas comentarios a tu codigo, entenderias que hace cada parte.. y podrias sacar la parte que te interesa.. intentalo, volve con ese intento y con gusto te vamos a ayudar!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Entiendo que necesitas un método diferente para la suma de cada fila

```
public class Metodos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] matriz = {{1,3,2},{3,1,4},{32,54,1}};
        sumaFila1(matriz);
        sumaFila2(matriz);
        sumaFila3(matriz);
    }
    
    public static void sumaFila1(int[][] matriz){
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            suma += matriz[0][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Suma de la fila 1= " + suma);
    }
    public static void sumaFila2(int[][] matriz){
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            suma += matriz[1][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Suma de la fila 2= " + suma);
    }
    public static void sumaFila3(int[][] matriz){
        int suma = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz.length; i++) {
            suma += matriz[2][i];
        }
        System.out.println("Suma de la fila 3= " + suma);
    }
}
```

Espero sea lo que buscas :)

Comment: Y que pasaria si la matriz tuviera una dimension de 100x100, harias 100 metodos para sumar cada fila? Tu respuesta no es optima

Comment: La respuesta es correcta.. pero me parece que por un solo metodo, es uno solo... no tres.. de igual forma tu respuesta es solo codigo y no esta explicada.. mira [answer]. y de paso, en las preguntas que son claramente ejercicios, solemos tratar de orientar.. no dar la solucion sin mas.. si no, no se aprende nada...

Comment: x2 a lo que dijo @Japv, ¿por qué no simplemente declarar el método `sumarFila(int i)` y que sume los elementos de la fila `i`?

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo, es justo lo que estaba buscando, de hecho igual tengo que sumar cada columna y cada diagonal y hacer un método para cada una, pero lo que quería era que me orientaras, con haber hecho de una fila hubiera sido suficiente, pero muchísimas gracias

Comment: De hecho si son varios métodos, ya que mi ejercicio me pide que haga un método por cada fila, uno por cada columna, y uno por cada diagonal

Comment: @gbianchi de acuerdo, muchas gracias por el consejo para responder claro que lo revisaré

Comment: @ArturoRodríguez uno para las filas no es lo mismo que uno para cada fila.. cuidado con eso.. si como profesor me entregas algo asi, te mato...

Comment: @gbianchi me dejaron hacer uno para cada fila amigo, no uno para las 3 filas, pero gracias por tu aporte

Comment: @ArturoRodríguez Recuerda aceptar la respuesta si te sirvio...